# url replace using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Looking to change the href in div big, src is working with the javascript below, at the moment clicking image one and two chages src but i need to change href aswell.

HTML

```
<div id="thumbnails">
<img src="http://imagelink.com/1.jpg" ><img src="htpp://imagelink.com/2.jpg"> 
</div>

<div id="big">
<a href="http://imagelink.com/1.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img src="http://imagelink.com/1.jpg"></a></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#thumbnails img").click(function(){
var temp = $(this).attr("src");
var temp2 = $("#big img").attr("src");
if(temp != temp2)
{
$("#big img").attr("src",temp);
}
});
});
```

Comment: And your problem with that is?

Comment: `$('#big a').attr('href',newHref )` you can the href value this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got the question right, I think something like this should work:

```
if(temp != temp2) {
    $("#big img").attr("src",temp);
    $("#big a").attr("href", temp);
}
```